# How to loop through array and push it into a seperate array based on some conditions using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array named "all_items" and i want to split that to two arrays named "self" and "others".

I want to loop through each item in "all_items" array and if that item is added by current_user then push it to "self" array if not "others" array

```
item = {
    id: 0,
    owner_id: 1, 
    name: "name",
}
```

Below is the algorithm,

```
group = () => {
    const self = [];
    const others = [];
    for each item
        if item is uploaded by current_user
            self.push(item)
        else
            others.push(item)
    return {self, others}
}
```

How can i implement the above in react or javascript. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What does an item in all_items look like? You'd need some sort of identifier to determine who uploaded it, and some sort of identifier for the user to know who they are.

Comment: thanks edited the question, if item.owner_id === current_user.id should do it.

Comment: you can compare your `current_user` id to id in the Object, if true add to self else add to `others`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to approach this problem. I think the cleanest approach in terms of readability and length is to leverage Javascript's built in prototype [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
const self = all_items.filter(item => item.owner === current_user);
const others = all_items.filter(item => item.owner !== current_user);
```

Or for a solution that mirrors your example algorithm more closely, you can iterate over `all_items` with [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and push values to `self` and `others` as you go.

```
const self = [];
const others = [];

all_items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.owner === current_user) {
    self.push(item);  
  } else {
    others.push(item);
  }
});
```

**Also note that `===` will compare both type and value.

Answer (score 1):

A much better aproach is to use filter as follows

```
const group = () => {
  const items = [
 {
    id: 0,
    owner_id: 1, 
    name: "name",
},
 {
    id: 2,
    owner_id: 2, 
    name: "user 2",
}
];
let current_user = { id: 1, name: "current user"}

const result = items.filter(item => item.owner_id != current_user.id);
const result2 = items.filter(item => item.owner_id == current_user.id);

  return { result, result2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`

```
var all_items = [{
    id: 0,
    owner_id: 1, 
    name: "Matt",
},
{
    id: 1,
    owner_id: 2, 
    name: "Dave",
},
{
    id: 2,
    owner_id: 1, 
    name: "Mike",
},
{
    id: 3,
    owner_id: 3, 
    name: "Jack",
},
{
    id: 4,
    owner_id: 1, 
    name: "Paul",
}];

var current_user = {
    id: 1
};

// self
console.log(all_items.filter(function(item){
    return item.owner_id === current_user.id;
}));

// others
console.log(all_items.filter(function(item){
    return item.owner_id !== current_user.id;
}));
```